# Using a single Core Data model in multiple projects

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have a set of related projects that will all use an identical Core Data model.  One OS X app for entering the data, which will be exported to another OS X app that will act as a server, and an iOS app that will act as a client.  Each client will maintain its own local store and changes on the server will be sent to the clients on MOCDidSave: over TCP on a local network.

I'd like to share a single model and a single set of the mogenerator-generated NSManagedObject subclasses throughout development in all projects / targets / apps.

I've looked at using a Workspace and using a single project with multiple targets.  I've also looked at the solution Marcus Zarra used to add a desktop version of the iOS app developed in the second edition of his Core Data book.  I'm sure there are also other ways of accomplishing this, but I'm unfamiliar with creating static libraries or frameworks and I'm not sure that's the right approach for this problem.

Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this?  Or, at least some idea of what the trade-offs will be?

Thanks.

Brad

Answer (score 0):

This isn't difficult to do.

Basically keep all your CoreData related classes and models in a detached folder system which you can add to your CoreData projects.

I have tried in the past to use a single self-contained data stack object layer i.e something which fires up the Persistent Store Coordinator, Persistent Store  and Managed Object Contexts which can be instantiated on iOS or OS X but it gets sticky once you start using NSPersistentDocument so in the end I just build the stack and point it at the common model and MOGenerated classes for each platform in the most efficient way for the given platform.

---

**EDIT**

The OP mentions that this is a B2B application and that they wont be using 'NSDocument'/'NSPersistentDocument' to handle things on the OS X side so a Container Object could be a good choice here. its duties would be to manage and instantiate the CoreData stack.
It would be written in such a way that it compiles on both OS X and iOS. So to fire up the data layer all you need to do is instantiate the object and ask for a managedObjectContext.

Have a look at [this blog by Florien Kugler](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/2/the-concurrent-core-data-stack) for some potential internal setup methods

---

**Advantages**

Your apps use a common data layer and all the free stuff that comes with CoreData

**Disadvantages**

Unless you use wrappered files Sandboxing will cause you much pain on OS X unless you don't plan on going via the MAS

NSPersistentDocument doesn't support wrappered files out of the box. Several people have made adapters. Check on GitHub. But maybe you don't plan on going down that road.

Versioning. Make sure your model is as correct as it can be before deploying as any Data Model change will force mandatory upgrades on all clients. And although Managed Object Model changes are fairly easy they do have a certain amount of finger crossing when it comes to deployment to your customers. Add in extra unused fields for future expansion.

Basically work out whether you really wish to use CoreData for this.  It's been said before but I'll paraphrase - CoreData is NOT a relational database it's a snazzy version of fopen().

A possible method is to use CoreData as a shim working layer in the App but keep the store as simple JSON layer on disk thus if the model needs to change radically at some future point you don't run the risk of frying all your client data.

In summary. Think long and hard about whether CoreData is suitable for your app and its long term prospect. It might be fine now but 2 years down track you might find yourself in hell.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy and detailed response.  It's not going to go through MAS and it'll be a B2B app for iOS (I'll basically be selling it to myself and doing each installation myself, so, I'll have a lot of contact with each deployment).  I won't be using NSPersistentDocument, either.

Comment: Ideally, I'd have a single folder for the "Workspace" and individual folders within that folder for each project + another folder for the data model and MO subclasses.  But, once the data model is outside of the main bundle of each of the projects, how best to include it in each bundle so changes are reflected?

Comment: You just include it. The build-chain doesnt care where things are it just needs to know the location of the model and it will compile it into the finished products. TBH this is where a framework might make things easier for you as you will be able to make it a dependant target for the build.